# Add item to the woocommerce dashboard menu from a plugin

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I was wondering if there's a way to add a menu item to access my plugin settings on the Woocommerce menu dashboard.

[image]

I've tried using the admin_menu hook, but no success at all.

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

try this code. Paste in to function.php

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_page');
function custom_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'Name of page', 'Name of item', 'manage_options', 'custom-slug', 'custom_page_content' ); 
}
function custom_page_content() {
    echo 'Page content';
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The menu option is not appearing under the WooCommerce menu

Comment: @EduardoChaparroAlire Yes, i tested it and work it. Down is screen